Fundamental lemma of sieve theory in function fields
Is there any literature concerning the fundamental lemma of sieve theory in $\mathbb{F}_q[T]$?
In integers there are various versions of the lemma (bases on different sieves); I would be happy with any of the versions.
I only found the Selberg sieve, the pure Brun sieve and the large sieve done in $\mathbb{F}_q[T]$, but nothing about the fundamental lemma.
Motivation: I want to use a function field (i.e. $\mathbb{F}_q[T]$-) version of this lemma.

I am not aware of any such write-up in the literature. It would be a fun exercise to write this down though
